# How to get data from Soap service by jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, soap, cordova

I want to get data from Webservice( Soap), but it not successfull. My service herehttp://icafe.ipos.vn/WSUitility/evsServiceUtility.svc?wsdl
I use jquery to request to service, code below

```
    var soap = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
        "<soap:Body>" +
        "<Test xmlns=''>" +
        "</Test>" +
        "</soap:Body>" +
        "</soap:Envelope>";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://icafe.ipos.vn/WSUitility/evsServiceUtility.svc?wsdl',
        method: 'post',
        data: soap,
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "urn:evsServiceUtility/Test1");
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(SOAPResponse) {
            alert('ok');
        },
        error: function(SOAPResponse) {
            alert('no ok');
        }
    });
```

And my service:

```
    public string Test()
    {
        try
        {
            return "Successfull!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

I spended many many times to search and try many solutions but it not working.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: I get code response 400 bad request.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your data type can be XML, not a problem there. Question is, how do you encode your `data` or parameters? Perhaps check the response in the POST request in the console of your browser.

I picked up a few things in c# to enable this automatically which is nicely documented here:
http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/

Then one thing left to do was to `JSON.stringify()` the data. So `bhRequest` is a json object right?

... and then cross browser you'll have to implement json2.js:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: Sr. bhRequest is soap variable above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your var named soap is being used. It looks like it should be the "data: " that's being sent to the SOAP service, but there's something called bhRequest there instead.

Also make sure you're allowing Phonegap access to your remote server with

```
<access subdomains="true" origin="*" />
```

in your config.xml. When you get things working you can make it more restrictive by limiting it to your icafe.ipos.vn domain.

Comment: Yes. In config.xml <access origin="*" />